# Number of mysql user Connections in a date range

Tags: mysql, count, connection

Have a database. How can I get the total number of connections for a user?
e,g database name: north_wind
database user: smuwanga

How do I know that smuwanga made 200 connections to the database in the last 3 months?

Regards,
Simon.

Comment: connection means 200 query's or something else??

Answer (score 0):

MySQL does not keep a connection log by default. However, if you want to find out current connections and users, you can use `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST`.

If you still insist on logging user connections, you may want to [check out this blog post with steps](http://mysqlhints.blogspot.sg/2011/01/how-to-log-user-connections-in-mysql.html) on how you can accomplish that.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get my way around it. 
I did a `grep 'mysql_username' /path/to/mysql.log |grep Connect | wc -l`

Its seems when installing mysql I left everything as default.